# Where does ElasticSearch store an index by default?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently indexing a large volume of data into ElasticSearch and I am not entirely sure where ES is actually storing the indices. My worries are that the indices are growing too large and might take up the entire space I have available on disk. In this sense, I would like to move them elsewhere (by creating snapshots and restoring them).

In the configuration it is specified that the actual location of the indices is /path/to/data, but inside my data folder I simply cannot find them. Also, is it possible to leave ES in the current location and point it to store indices in a different place?

Comment: And what about other paths? Also are you sure that it's really set to /path/to/data and it's not just a commented out configuration line?

Comment: @JiriS: Yes, this line appears to be commented out by default. In haven't changed anything inside the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The default location for the index is < installation_folder>/data.

Yes, it is possible to change that value to something else, so you can have ES installed in one location, but the data will be in another. It is actually a best practice since it makes upgrades easier. In ES 1.6, its even possible for shadow replicas, meaning the index data can be shared by a couple of ES instances.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Indeed, found my indices inside the data folder. Could you please give me details on how these can be moved to another location? Do I need to change the elasticsearch configuration file to point elsewhere? Do I need to stop ES too?

Comment: I think it's safe to move the data folder entirely to a new location, but i'm not 100% sure.

Before you do that, you should stop the service and update the "path.data" setting in the elasticsearch.yml file.